# Java 11 GC1 GC memory management issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-11

I need some guidance related to Java 11 GC algorithm for JVM. We are migrating our application from jdk 8 to Java11. We are seeing spikes in memory management with the new GC algorithm that is defaulted with Java11 ie., GC1. Earlier we used CMS. Earlier our JVM startup params for the GC as below:
Application Infrastructure : 8 core CPU, 16GB RAM Linux EC2 (c5.2xlarge)

```
JDK 8 : -d64 -server -Xms4g -Xmx12g -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ThreadStackSize=1024 -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
```

Here we see the average memory usage at 4gb to 6gb when there is full load on the system.

```
Java11 : -server -Xms12g -Xmx12g -verbose:gc -Xlog:gc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xlog:safePoint -XX:ThreadStackSize=1024 -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
```

Here we see the average memory usage gradually increase and go up till 90% on full load and that's when the GC runs and frees up the space. Also, we do not see the memory usage coming down when there is no load or 0 load on the system. I read that this is the expected behavior of Gc1
Kindly Advice!
Application behavior is similar is both cases

Comment: That sounds just like normal behavior to me.  What makes you think it is not normal and/or problematic?

Comment: The memory consumption with the new GC looks weird! it always uses the entire heap and also doesn't release it till its needed

Comment: Ask the person who told you to specify the options `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30` and `-XX:G1ReservePercent=20` Apparently, this person is already an expert on G1GC and can tell you everything.

Comment: I set this up after several iterations of performance testing that is the reason i am a bit skeptical as there is no hard and fast rule for these flags to be set up.

Comment: So you tried out with the minimum set of behaviour flags and ended up where you are now?

Comment: Yes, That's right!